# Client side SQL monitor for Oracle database aplications

Tags: oracle, monitoring, client

We have custom application that connects to an Oracle database. We need a tool that is capable of running on the client machine (Windows 10/11) and is able to capture all SQL sent to the database, and show how long it takes to get response.

In the Windows 7 environment, we were able to use Quest Software SQL Monitor (Freeware). However, this tool does not work on Windows 10/11.

Main problem, is there a tool capable of capturing the application side SQL request and show if it is slow to receive a response?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t use windows but I can imagine that something like tcpdump als works on windows. With a little luck you can run go applications.

If that is true, you might be able to use https://github.com/ora600pl/stado that is not exactly like the quest tools but it does show sql and their response times as seen by the client.